# React Native version mismatch Js Version 0.50.4 Native Version 0.62.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm newbie in React Native working on a old project getting this error can't resolve it for the past couple of hours anyone pls help?

> JavaScript version: 0.50.4
>      Native version: 0.62.2
>
> Make sure that you have rebuilt the native code. If the problem persists try clearing the Watchman  and packager caches with `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache`.

This is how my package.json look like

```
{
  "name": "WhoopaUserApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest-expo": "^37.0.0",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/react-native": "^1.4.1",
    "ac-qrcode": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "errno": "^0.1.7",
    "expo": "^37.0.3",
    "fetchival": "^0.3.3",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.4.0",
    "jsc-android": "^241213.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.4",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.4",
    "react-native-cached-image": "^1.4.3",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",
    "react-native-config": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.6.3",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.10.43",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.24",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.6",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-swipe-out": "^2.0.14",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-swipeview": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-swiping-row": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-update-js": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.12.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "^5.4.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's been 4 days. I'm still struggling with this error.

Comment: You have an old instance of a Metro bundler running. Close it and run `react-native android` or `react-native ios` again. If you can't find it, restart the computer.

Comment: I've restarted computer tried a lot. could you please explain it more?

Comment: The error message means that the project uses React Native version 0.50.4 but the phone or emulator is using version 0.62.2. Possibly if you're using a global instance of react-native-cli its version doesn't match the project version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GuyIncognito. I've updated my question added `package.json` i've downgraded my react-native version from `0.62.2` to  `^0.61.4` as you can see in my package.json file. How i can update my Java Script version to update to meet the match my react-native version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for days Finally i solved it.

1. First Delete `index.android.bundle` (Located in Assets folder under android project)
2. Run command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` (I replaced `index.js` to `App.js`)